# jQuery: Duplicating file input groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to duplicate my file input groups, so that when the user selects a file to upload, it automatially creates another file upload field and description field.

This works fine, except for when I change the file of a file I've already selected an input for. When I do that, it duplicates ALL the file input groups.

Any insight into why this is going on?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/czLmbjd6/4/

HTML:

```
    <div id = "add-photos">
    <input type="file"></input>
        <label>Description:</label>
        <input type = "text"></input>
    </div>

    <div id = "additional-photos">
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    bindFileInputs();
});

function bindFileInputs(){
    $("input:file").change(function (){
        addPhotoField();
    });
}


function addPhotoField() {
    var id = 1; //standin for now, will dynamically update this number later
    createPhotoField(id);
}

function createPhotoField(id){

    var p = $("#add-photos");

    p.clone().appendTo("#additional-photos").removeAttr("id").children().find('input,select').each(function(){
        $(this).val('');

        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'file'){
            console.log("type is file");
            $(this).attr('name', 'data[Image][' + id + '][image]');
        }

        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'text'){
            console.log("type is text");
            $(this).attr('name', 'data[Image][' + id + '][description]');
        }

        });
    bindFileInputs();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  bindFileInputs($('#add-photos input[type="file"]'));
});

function bindFileInputs(input) {
  //use one() to register a handler which will be fired only once
  input.one('change', function() {
    addPhotoField();
  });
}


function addPhotoField() {
  var id = 1; //standin for now, will dynamically update this number later
  createPhotoField(id);
}

function createPhotoField(id) {

  var p = $("#add-photos");

  var $clone = p.clone().appendTo("#additional-photos").removeAttr("id");

  $clone.find('input,select').val('');
  $clone.find('input:text').attr('name', 'data[Image][' + id + '][description]');
  var $file = $clone.find('input:file').attr('name', 'data[Image][' + id + '][image]');
  bindFileInputs($file)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select a file with the file upload control. It should create a new file input group.
<div id="add-photos">
  <input type="file" />
  <label>Description:</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div id="additional-photos"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        bindFileInputs();
    });

    function bindFileInputs(){
        $("input:file").change(function (){

            if($('.newF').length ==0 ){
                createPhotoField(Number($(this).attr('id'))+1);
            }
            if($(this).hasClass('newF')){
             createPhotoField(Number($(this).attr('id'))+1);
            }
        });
    }




    function createPhotoField(id){
        $('.newF').removeClass('newF')
         id+=1;
        var p = $("<div/>");
 p.appendTo("#additional-photos"); 

        p.html('<input class="newF" id= "'+id+'" type="file"></input><label>Description:</label><input type = "text"></input>')

        p.children().find('input,select').each(function(){
            $(this).val('');

            if ($(this).attr('type') == 'file'){
                console.log("type is file");
                $(this).attr('name', 'data[Image][' + id + '][image]');
            }

            if ($(this).attr('type') == 'text'){
                console.log("type is text");
                $(this).attr('name', 'data[Image][' + id + '][description]');
            }

            })
        bindFileInputs();
    }
```

UPDATED FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/czLmbjd6/12/

Comment: Hm- that still has the same bug where it creates far too many fields when you change the file selected in an input.

Answer (score 1):

See your call of `bindFileInputs();` in `createPhotoField`. You are adding another handler to `change` event of all `$("input:file")` elements in your page. If you change the file in any of these elements (except the last one), `addPhotoField` will fire two or more times.

Do:

```
var newItem = p.clone();
newItem.appendTo("#additional-photos").removeAttr("id").children().find('input,select').each(function(){
  ...
});

// instead of bindFileInputs();
newItem.find("input:file").change(function (){
   addPhotoField();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well try this

```
<div id = "add-photos">
<input type="file" inuse="false"></input>
    <label>Description:</label>
    <input type = "text"></input>
</div>

<div id = "additional-photos">
</div>





    $(document).ready(function(){
    bindFileInputs();
});

function bindFileInputs(){
    $("input:file").change(function (){   

        if($(this).attr('inuse') == "false"){
            addPhotoField();                
        }          
        $(this).attr('inuse', 'true');
    });
}

var id = 0;
function addPhotoField() {
    id += 1; //standin for now, will dynamically update this number later
    createPhotoField(id);
}

function createPhotoField(id){
    $("#add-photos").find('input:file').attr('inuse', 'false');
    var p = $("#add-photos");

    p.clone().appendTo("#additional-photos").removeAttr("id").children().find('input,select').each(function(){
        $(this).val('');

        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'file'){
            console.log("type is file");
            $(this).attr('name', 'data[Image][' + id + '][image]');
            $(this).attr('inuse', 'false');
        }

        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'text'){
            console.log("type is text");
            $(this).attr('name', 'data[Image][' + id + '][description]');
        }

        });
    $("#add-photos").find('input:file').attr('inuse', 'true');
    bindFileInputs();
}
```